# Finding matching objects in an array of objects?

Tags: javascript

```
var set = [{"color":"blue"},{"color":"green"},{"color":"red"},{"color":"green"}];
```

I'd like to be able to do something like a db call, `set.find({"color":"green"})` and have it return an array full of objects that contain that property.

Comment: Already answered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1820593/search-a-javascript-object

Comment: That example doesn't return the whole object, does it?

Comment: This has nothing to do with jQuery, so you should remove that tag. It is a purely JavaScript question.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Using [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Filter), for this particular case the code would look like

```
var results = set.filter(function (entry) { return entry.color === "green"; });
```

`Array#filter` is not implemented in some older browsers, so see the linked article for a backward compatibility shim, or better yet get [a full-fledged ES5 shim](https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim/).

For the more general case, it's just a matter of extending this idea:

```
function findByMatchingProperties(set, properties) {
    return set.filter(function (entry) {
        return Object.keys(properties).every(function (key) {
            return entry[key] === properties[key];
        });
    });
}

var results = findByMatchingProperties(set, { color: "green" });
```

Again, I am using ECMAScript 5 methods [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every), so use an ES5 shim. (The code is doable without an ES5 shim but uses manual loops and is much less fun to write and read.)

Comment: Even weirder that you're including the jQuery tag then.

Comment: what would this look like as a method? set.find({color:"green"}), basically looking to create faux db functionality.

Comment: @float, are you looking to add this method to all arrays, or just your custom objects, or...? If the former, what do you expect it to do for an array of integers?

Comment: it could just be on a user object, so findUser() finds their object in the user array - doesn't need to be a general method.

Comment: Well you're welcome to post a followup question on how methods work in JavaScript, but just to get you started, `var users = { users: [], findUser: function (properties) { return findByMatchingProperties(this.users, properties); } };`

Comment: I assume there aren't any problems using this in angular 2.  Correct?

Answer (score 3):

I have used map function from jquery and I am getting selected index by passing searched key value so by using that index we will get required object from array.

```
var mydata = [{ name: "Ram", Id: 1 }, { name: "Shyam", Id: 2 }, { name: "Akhil", Id: 3 }];

searchKey = 2
```

```js
var mydata = [{ name: "Ram", Id: 1 }, { name: "Shyam", Id: 2 }, { name: "Akhil", Id: 3 }];

searchKey = 2

var selectedData = mydata[mydata.map(function (item) { return item.Id; }).indexOf(searchKey)];

console.log(selectedData)
```

```
var selectedData = mydata[mydata.map(function (item) { return item.Id; }).indexOf(searchKey)];

console.log(selectedData)

output
{ name: "Shyam", Id: 2 }

Note: if you want to pass search key as object then
searchKey = { Id: 2 };

mydata[mydata.map(function (item) { return item.Id; }).indexOf(searchKey.Id)];

output
{ name: "Shyam", Id: 2 }
```

Comment: jQuery's map function is exactly what I needed. Your code snippet is great and was the first one to suggest using map, so I up-voted yours.

Answer (score 3):

Using arrow functions with an implied `return` and concise body:

`const results = set.filter(entry => entry.color === "green");`

Another example passing in a search variable:

```
const searchString = 'green'; 
const results = set.filter(entry => entry.color === `${searchString}`);
```

Read more about arrow functions on
[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Answer (score 1):

Since you've included the jQuery tag, here's one way to do it using jQuery's [`map`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/):

```
var results = $.map( set, function(e,i){
  if( e.color === 'green' ) return e; 
});
```

The documentation states that you need to return `null` to remove the element from the array, but apparently this is false, as shown by the jsFiddle in the comments; returning nothing (i.e. returning `undefined`) works just as well.

Comment: This will return `[undefined, { color: "green" }, undefined, undefined]`.

Comment: @Ken Redler, I stand corrected. The documentation for `$.map` says it will only remove the element if you return `null`, but I guess it recognizes `undefined` as well. Still, I think usually you'd want to use `$.grep` for this.

Comment: @Domenic, I do see that point about `null` in the documentation, but as far as I know it's always worked with the `undefined` of a function that has no return in some cases. I.e., omitting the return statement entirely has always resulted in an array with zero elements, if I recall correctly.

Comment: @Ken Redler, yup, I believe you; I just think it sucks that their documentation doesn't mention this.

Comment: @Domenic, I agree. I've submitted a documentation update suggestion to the jQuery team.

Comment: You're better off using filter - map is functionally for changing a list of type A -> list of type B with the same number of elements.  I'm not saying it doesn't work, but it's using the wrong tool for the job.

Answer (score 0):

I went with a different approach that I found to be a bit easier.

```js
function isObjEqual(a, b) {
    const x = JSON.stringify(a);
    const y = JSON.stringify(b);
  
    return x === y;
  }

// Example 1
const set = [{"color":"blue"},{"color":"green"},{"color":"red"},{"color":"green"}];
const findObj1 = {"color":"green"};
const arr1 = set.filter((objInArr) => isObjEqual(objInArr, findObj1));
console.log(arr1) // [ { color: 'green' }, { color: 'green' } ]

  // Example 2
const list = [{
    "label": "Option 2",
    "value": "option2"
  },
  {
    "label": "Option 3",
    "value": "option3"
  },
  {
    "label": "Option 2",
    "value": "option2"
  }
];

const findObj2 = {
  "label": "Option 2",
  "value": "option2"
}

const newList = list.filter((objInArr) => isObjEqual(objInArr, findObj2));
console.log(newList) //[ { label: 'Option 2', value: 'option2' }, { label: 'Option 2', value: 'option2' } ]
```