# Display error message when two ID has same value in an array using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

[image]

I have a array like this which has same tid i want to compare this array and display error message as duplicate ID is present

Comment: That is a JavaScript array of JavaScript objects. Not JSON.

Comment: Possible dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6237537/finding-matching-objects-in-an-array-of-objects

Comment: If the following is true then you don't have duplicates: `data.length === new Set(data.map(d=>d.Tid)).size`

Comment: @HMR this is showing false

Comment: If the following is true then you **don't** have duplicates, if it shows false then you do have duplicates.

Comment: @HMR thanks i got solution for based on your condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do it:

```
array.forEach(function(e,i){
  for (var j = i+1; j < array.length; j++) {
     if (e.Tid == array[j].Tid) {
        // ids match, do something
     }
   }
 });
```