# How to search a string in all properties of an object in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Can anybody tell how to search for a string in all properties. If match in some property I need to push the object in array in AngularJS.

I have an array

```
$scope.ListOfPeople = [
    { PersonID: 10, FirstName: "John", LastName: "Smith", Sex: "Male" },
    { PersonID: 11, FirstName: "James", LastName: "Last", Sex: "Male" },
    { PersonID: 12, FirstName: "Mary", LastName: "Heart", Sex: "Female" },
    { PersonID: 13, FirstName: "Sandra", LastName: "Goldsmith", Sex: "Female" },
    { PersonID: 14, FirstName: "Shaun", LastName: "Sheep", Sex: "Male" },
    { PersonID: 15, FirstName: "Nicola", LastName: "Smith", Sex: "Male" }
];
```

If the user types some value in search textbox. I need to search with PersonID, FirstName, LastName, Sex with all properties if it is match need to push the matched object.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to search JSON tree with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5288833/how-to-search-json-tree-with-jquery)

Comment: What have you tried so far ? There's lot of documentation on internet about the search filter

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10679626/5115768 you tried this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Search a javascript object for a property with a specific value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9422756/search-a-javascript-object-for-a-property-with-a-specific-value)

Answer (score 2):

I think Angular's [Filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) filter will do what you are looking for

```
<input ng-model="search"/>
<div ng-repeat="person in ListOfPeople | filter:search">
    {{person}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like that ?

```
for(var index in $scope.ListOfPeople) { 
   if ($scope.ListOfPeople.hasOwnProperty(index)) {
       if($scope.ListOfPeople[index] == "Your string") {
           // Do something here 
       }
   }
}
```