# How could I find a json object by id using nodejs/js

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

So I want to get the object by the id 1 in this object:

```
let users = {
  'users': {
    'user1': {
      'id': '1',
      'name': 'Brandon',
      'DOB': '05/04/2000'
    },
    'user2': {
      'id': '2',
      'name': 'Jefferson',
      'DOB': '05/19/2004'
    }
  }
}
```

and I want it to return the entire 'user1' array and log it, does anyone know how I could do this?

I looked all over stackoverflow, and docs, and couldn't find a way to do this. Could I get some help?

Comment: Did you looked for `Object.entries` and `find` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to deep filter objects (not object arrays)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50012040/how-to-deep-filter-objects-not-object-arrays)

Answer (score 1):

There are a few approaches, both of these should roughly achieve what you're looking for:

```js
let users = {
  'users': {
    'user1': {
      'id': '1',
      'name': 'Brandon',
      'DOB': '05/04/2000'
    },
    'user2': {
      'id': '2',
      'name': 'Jefferson',
      'DOB': '05/19/2004'
    }
  }
}

const findUserById = (id) => {
  const key = Object.keys(users.users).find(user => users.users[user].id === '1')
  return users.users[key]
}

console.log(findUserById('1'))
```

```js
let users = {
  'users': {
    'user1': {
      'id': '1',
      'name': 'Brandon',
      'DOB': '05/04/2000'
    },
    'user2': {
      'id': '2',
      'name': 'Jefferson',
      'DOB': '05/19/2004'
    }
  }
}

const findUserById = (id) => {
  const [key, user] = Object.entries(users.users).find(([key, user]) => user.id === '1');
  return user;
}

console.log(findUserById('1'))
```

Answer (score 1):

While the answer by skovy is right and this is what you should be doing in an actual production setting, I would advise against applying it immediately in your situation.

Why? Your question shows that you first need to learn some basic principles any JavaScript programmer should have, that is:

**How to iterate over contents of an object**

The simplest method used to iterate over an object's keys is the `for .. in` loop. When iterating over an object's keys using the `for .. in` loop, the code inside the curly brackets will be executed once for every key of the object we are iterating.

```
let users = {
   "user1": {
       "id": 1
   },
   "user2": {
       "id": 2
   }
}
for (let key in users) {
    console.log(key);
}
```

The above code will print:

```
user1
user2
```

Proceeding from that, it should be clear how to find the element we want:

```
let foundUser = null;
for (let key in users) {
    if (users[key].id === 1) {
        foundUser = users[key];
        break;
    }
}
// now found user is our user with id === 1 or null, if there was no such user
```

**When not to do that**

If you have a complex object which is a descendant of another object and don't want to iterate over inherited properties, you could instead get an array of current object's keys with `Object.keys`:

```
let users = {
   "user1": {
       "id": 1
   },
   "user2": {
       "id": 2
   }
}
const keys = Object.keys(users) // now this is an array containing just keys ['user1', 'user2'];
let foundUser = null;
// now you can iterate over the `keys` array using any method you like, e.g. normal for:
for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    if (users[keys[i]].id === 1) {
        foundUser = users[keys[i]];
        break;
    }
}
// or alternatively `for of`:
for (for key of keys) {
    if (users[key].id === 1) {
        foundUser = users[key];
        break;
    }
}
```

**Other options**

You could use `Object.values` to get an array containing all values of the object:

```
let users = {
   "user1": {
       "id": 1
   },
   "user2": {
       "id": 2
   }
}
const values = Object.values(users); // values: [{"id":1},{"id":2}]
```

You can now find the entry you want on your own:

```
let foundUser = null
for (let i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    if (values[i].id === 1) {
        foundUser = values[i];
        break;
    }
}
```

Or using the Array's [find method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find):

```
let foundUser = values.find(user => user.id === 1);
// now foundUser contains the user with id === 1
```

Or, shorter and complete version:

```
let users = {
   "user1": {
       "id": 1
   },
   "user2": {
       "id": 2
   }
}
const foundUser = Object.values(users).find(user => user.id === 1);
// now foundUser is `{ id: 1 }`
```

Comment: Hi Andrei,  hope you could help me with my doubt. i have a json and still i couldn't grab my head how to parse it in js/node js

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57946100/how-could-i-find-a-json-object-by-id-using-nodejs-js .! here i have posted the problem of mine

Comment: @suryakiran you parse the json string with `JSON.parse(jsonString)`, it returns json object. And your link points to this question, not to yours.

Answer (score 1):

Not a big fan of reinventing the wheel. We use [object-scan](https://github.com/blackflux/object-scan) for most of our data processing now. It's very handy when you can just use a tool for that kind of stuff. Just takes a moment to wrap your head around how to use it. Here is how it could answer your questions:

```js
// const objectScan = require('object-scan');

const find = (id, data) => objectScan(['**.id'], {
  abort: true,
  rtn: 'parent',
  filterFn: ({ value }) => value === id
})(data);

const users = { users: { user1: { id: '1', name: 'Brandon', DOB: '05/04/2000' }, user2: { id: '2', name: 'Jefferson', DOB: '05/19/2004' } } };

console.log(find('1', users));
// => { id: '1', name: 'Brandon', DOB: '05/04/2000' }
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/object-scan@13.8.0"></script>
```

*Disclaimer*: I'm the author of [object-scan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-scan)

Answer (score 0):

A simple for loop would do it:

```js
let users = {
    'users': {
      'user1': {
        'id': '1',
        'name': 'Brandon',
        'DOB': '05/04/2000'
      },
      'user2': {
        'id': '2',
        'name': 'Jefferson',
        'DOB': '05/19/2004'
      }
    }
  }
let desiredUser = {};
Object.keys(users.users).forEach((oneUser) => {
    if(users.users[oneUser].id === "1")
        desiredUser = users.users[oneUser];
    
});   

console.log(desiredUser);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `reduce` for this... as well as if you wanted to return the "entire" object, you could do:

```js
let USER_LIST = {
  'users': {
    'user1': {
      'id': '1',
      'name': 'Brandon',
      'DOB': '05/04/2000'
    },
    'user2': {
      'id': '2',
      'name': 'Jefferson',
      'DOB': '05/19/2004'
    }
  }
}

function findUserById(id){
  return Object.entries(USER_LIST.users).reduce((a, [user, userData]) => {
    userData.id == id ? a[user] = userData : '';
    return a;
  }, {});
}

console.log(findUserById(1));
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the Answers. just a short and simple way is to use .find() method

```
 //--data returned-----//
 data = [{"Id":22,"Title":"Developer"},{"Id":45,"Title":"Admin"}]


      fs.readFile('db.json','utf8', function(err,data){
            var obj = JSON.parse(data);
            console.log(obj);
            var foundItem = obj.find(o=>o.Id==id);
            console.log(foundItem);
       });
```