# Regular Expression look for string and return everything between curly braces

Tags: javascript, regex, curly-braces

I've been trying to use the approach suggested by another SO-User: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1820837/1324861

But without luck. Basically, I have a large JSON Object that I transformed into a string using `JSON.stringify()` in order to execute a regexp pattern against. My idea is to return everything between `{ }` if my search term "soccer" is found anywhere between the curly braces.

My data could look like this:

```
{
  {
    User: "Peter",
    Hobbies: "Soccer, Football, ...",
    more...
  },
  {
    User: "Simon",
    Hobbies: "Pingpong, Soccer, Badminton",
    more...
  }
}
```

So if I searched for 'soccer' in my stringified JSON Object I'd like to get back the entire info on the user. How can I do this?

Comment: You stringified an object just so you could use a regex to search something in it?

Comment: Is your JSON object so big that searching against it's string representation is faster?

Comment: Your JSON is not valid, the objects miss property names.

Comment: @madfriend umm, that would be slower.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not that it doesn't make sense to stringify a JSON object to apply a regex on it (shudder) but hey, it's your CPU... You could use something like this:

```
\{[^{]+soccer[^}]+}
```

This should catch what you're looking for. But... Parsing JSON with regexes... Nononono...

Comment: I'm not very happy with this approach either but it seems about the only one I can come up with because my JSON is dynamic and with variable depths (aka I may have data.cat1.subcat2.items[] and data.cat2.items[]) and I want to search over all items in all cat/subcats. - have more performant ideas how i could achieve that?

Comment: @opfeffer it doesn't matter what your JSON is, it's always easier, faster and less error-prone to search its object representation

Comment: @opfeffer Could you post a sample of your JSON? Maybe just a a couple of elements, with sub and sub-sub elements?

Answer (score 2):

You could inspire from this (**without transforming your json into string**):

```
var myData = [
  {
    User: "Peter",
    Hobbies: "Soccer, Football, ..."
  },
  {
    User: "Simon",
    Hobbies: "Pingpong, Soccer, Badminton"
  }
];
var results = "";
for (var i = 0; i < myData.length; i++) {
    if (myData[i]["Hobbies"].indexOf("Soccer") != -1) {
        results += JSON.stringify(myData [i]) + "\n";
    }                  
}
alert(results);
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like "{[^}]*(S|s)occer[^}]*}"

Answer (score 0):

```
var json = [
  {
    User: "Peter",
    Hobbies: "Soccer, Football, ..."
  },
  {
    User: "Simon",
    Hobbies: "Pingpong, Badminton"
  }
];


var jsonString = JSON.stringify(json);
var regEx = /(\{.*?Soccer.*?\})/;
var user = jsonString.match(regEx)[1];
document.write(user);
```