# How to show and center a single country polygon in leaflet?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, leaflet

I am trying to auto zoom to a specific country name when I load the page using [leaflet](http://leafletjs.com/). When I post my page, i can get a variable like:

```
var $myCountry = "France";
```

Now I load my json like:

```
$json = file_get_contents("/world.json");
$data = json_decode($json, true);
```

This is my geoJson  structure:

```
{
  "type":"Feature",
  "id":"AFG",
  "properties":{"name":"France"},
  "geometry":{
    "type":"Polygon",
    "coordinates":[
      [
        [61.210817,35.650072],
        [62.230651,35.270664]
      ]
  }
},
```

Basically I want to check if my variable name is equal to a name within the geoJson and if so I want to get the coordinates of it, something along those lines.

```
var $myCoordinates = $myCountry.coordinates
```

I want to do this in order to zoom in to a map based on the country name found in the variable, I have also checked this other [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27194497/check-if-a-string-is-in-a-json-object) but I didn't get it.

**UPDATE**

This almost works, the comparison between the variable and the propriety name isn't tho, yet the variable string is correct and wihtin the json we do have a name with the same string

```
var $country = "<?php echo $region; ?>";

$.ajax({ 
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/world.json', 
    data: { get_param: 'value' }, 
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) { 
    $.each(data, function(index, element) { 
        if (element.properties.name == $country) {
            alert("ciao");
        }
    });
    }
});
```

Comment: Will the value you want to check always be contained in `obj.properties.name`?

Comment: yes, the whole geoJson has the structure for all the countries as per what i wrote in the question

Comment: in which case please see the duplicate I marked for a solution

Comment: but that answer is not talking about json but an array in a variable

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan this shouldn't been marked as duplicate as what i am asking isn't what the duplicated question asked, even tho the solution maybe similar

Comment: So there is only ever one object returned? If so just use `if (obj.properties.name == 'France')` and then do what you require from there...?

Comment: yes that would do maybe, and be a correct answer if it works, i try now

Comment: Are you sure `file_get_contents` returns your data synchronously?

Comment: @ghybs changing the question code

Comment: Rory is probably correct here `success: function (data) { if (data.properties.name == $country) {}}` should be enough. But looking at the url `/spime/world.json` I see that you have multiple locations in an array being returned, so really it should be: `success: function (data) { 
        $.each(data, function(index, element) { if (element.properties.name == $country) {}}}` or something along those lines.

Comment: tried using jsonp too

Comment: You're echoing your PHP variable without using quotes. You probably have errors in your console.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan correct, check my updated code in the quetsion

Comment: Do you have any error in console?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think we were misled by how you initially showed your code and data structure, and your post title.

Actually you are not trying to scan an array or a simple JSON object, but a GeoJSON object with a FeatureCollection and lots of Features.

So you have to loop through that FeatureCollection's Feature, and scan each Feature's `properties.name`.

But even with that, you will still not be able to perform your objective of zooming onto the corresponding Leaflet layer: the GeoJSON object is not linked to your Leaflet layers, whereas the reverse is.

So you should instead build the [Leaflet GeoJSON group](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.3.html#geojson) out of your GeoJSON data, and then scan that group (e.g. using [`eachLayer()`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.3.html#layergroup-eachlayer)) to find the layer that is the representation of a Feature with `properties.name === "France"`.

Something in line of:

```js
$.getJSON('/world.json', function (geoJSONdata) {
    var geoJSONgroup = L.geoJSON(geoJSONdata).addTo(map);

    geoJSONgroup.eachLayer(function (layer) {
      if (layer.feature.properties.name === "France") {
        // Zoom to that layer.
        map.fitBounds(layer.getBounds());
      }
    });
});
```

Demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/SVJfLf8gR0VysrFVkwsS?p=preview

Comment: Oh man thanks so much, seriously. I have been hours and hours on this, tried any single hack possibile, i even ended up in Centroid_of_polygon, crazy. All of this simply because i didn't know about this feature. Thanks a lot